# vector with epsilon

Tags: geometry

if there are two points p1 and p2.and vector of both is ab ..

now if i say 
**-1 < ab < 1** 
 condition true than return F..

is that mean by points p1 and p2 intersect to each other...?

Comment: Please try to clarify your question. I don't get the connection between the question title and text. Do you have a link to point us to?

Comment: Voted to close because no clarification seems forthcoming and both the title and question are incomprehensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Points can not 'intersect'. They are either equal or they are not. If you create a vector based on points p1 and p2 then the vector will 'intersect' both points because that's what the vector was intended to do.

Comment: Plus, I don't get how a vector can be compared to a number.

Comment: ok if i sat ab<1 pr ab>1.. what does it mean.. is that mean by point p1 is not at pont p2.

Comment: if i say vector ab <0.0001 where ab is  a vector from point P1 and P2.. what means by ab<0.0001 and ab>-0.0001.